# What is the use case or purpose of declaring field as Serializable?

Tags: java, serializable

```
class B implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_DATE")
    private Serializable modifiedDate;
}
```

Is there any use case or purpose to declare `modifiedDate` as `Serializable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a good example,because modifiedDate can be a Date.
Think in this example:

```
class Message implements Serializable {
    private String senderName;
    private int messageType;
    private Serializable payload;
    ...
}
```

The Message can transport many kind of thing, but if you declared `payload` as Object, It can fail in Runtime, because not every Object can be serialized.

Comment: the example code given above was intentional, because I've seen this in one of our application, I don't know why previous developer declared modifiedDate as Serializable instead of Date, it give us extra effort to cast the field to Date. Anyway thanks for your response.